# Movement in Emacs using a Space-Modifier

Tags: emacs, customization

**Setup:** I am running a fairly vanilla version of [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) after I quit using Spacemacs some days ago (mainly because the usual evil-mode-incompatibities were grinding my gears).

**Problem:** I am having issues with the Emacs' movement commands, in particular because I am already getting a bit of an 'Emacs Pinky'. My current workaround is using [modalka-mode](https://github.com/mrkkrp/modalka) with h/j/k/l bindings. What I would love is a direct mapping of `<SPC>-h/j/k/l` to the corresponding Emacs commands `C-b/n/p/f`. This would require the space-key to be some sort of modifier when held down. Is my desired behavior achievable in Emacs, and if yes, how?

**Remark:** I do not want to use evil-mode, since I found the incompatibilities with other packages to be overly annoying.

Comment: IIUC what you are asking for, holding <SPC> down and pressing h/j/k/l would be a movement, while pressing  and releasing <SPC> would enter a space in the buffer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you think this will be an issue?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it might be. I certainly don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for mode called "space-chord".

It is installable with melpa or here:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/space-chord.el

You might want to look into key chords also:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord

They are awesome, especially with evil mode. For example I have "jk" bound to normal mode instead of escape or C-[.